# How to call a javascript function as well as save the form data into a text file in a html page?

Tags: javascript, html

here is my html code.....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Plot</title>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function refilter()
    {
        var ch = document.getElementById('Choice').value;
        //do something
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="save.php" name="myform" method="POST">
    Select any station:<select id="Choice" name="choice">
        <option value="None">Select</option>
        <option value="option1">DELHI</option>
        <option value="option2">MUMBAI</option>
        </select>
     <input type="button" onclick="refilter()" value="Submit!">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I wish to do two things:
1.save the "choice" entered by user, since I have to do further task using it and
2.call the "refilter" function.

As of now, I tried using php and store the "choice" in a text file but for that i need to change "input type=submit" and if I do so,

1.The function is not called.
2.the save.php file opens up, which i dont want. I wish to stay on the html page only.

I am a beginner to javascript and html and knew a little php, so tried my hand at that.

Is there anyway I can do both the tasks together?

Comment: research submitting form using ajax, will find lots of tutorials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do following with your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Plot</title>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
   <script>
    window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('test').onclick = function(event) {
        document.getElementById('myform').submit();
        // Do somthing
    }
}
</script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="save.php" name="myform" id="myform">
    Select any station:<select id="Choice" name="choice">
        <option value="None">Select</option>
        <option value="option1">DELHI</option>
        <option value="option2">MUMBAI</option>
        </select>
     <input type="button" value="Submit!" id="test">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

or you can follow: http://www.formget.com/form-submission-using-ajax-php-and-javascript/

Thanks.

Comment: thnks @Naitik....with the help of the link you provided, I was able to achieve what I wanted. Just went through that link and learnt a bit about ajax and bingo!! :D

Comment: @Sush if answer helps you make it as answer so other who face same problem can get answer too. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you want to have both the default behavior as well as your custom behavior.

Here's a simple solution you can try.

```
<form action="save.php" name="myform" method="POST" id="myform">

<input type="button" id="submit-btn" value="Submit" />
```

In javascript,

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('submit-btn').onclick = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        refilter();
        document.getElementById('myform').submit();
    }
}
```

This will redirect the page to save.php anyway. If you don't want that, you can send a POST request via AJAX. Please find more about AJAX and post if you still face problems